# Как назначить папку для файлов программ в виртуальном окружении Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.7, virtualenv

Создал виртуальное окружение в папке work3.7, в которой лежат папки lib, bin, include и другие. Если файл с программой на python располагаю тут же в корне, то все работает. Создал папку projects, но программы в ней при запуске выдают ошибку подключения cv2 или numpy, подскажите, как это настроить?

Comment: Я полагаю это на windows, если да, то не подскажу. Если linux, то можно активировать venv путем `source env_path/bin/activate`, либо в шебанге указать путь к интерпретатору в venv

Comment: linux ubuntu 18.04, все активировано и работает, если файлы лежат тут же, я хочу собрать их в отдельной папке, но в папке они не работают

Comment: Можете привести пример структуры каталога, как вы их хотите собрать? А то не слишком понятно, потому что "собрать их в отдельной папке" звучит подозрительно. Собирайте сколько угодно,  но запускайте главный файл из `venv`, а из папок уже подтягиваются пакеты

Comment: Да, конечно.  Папка work3.7, в ней -bin, -lib, -include и др. Это все создается автоматически. Моя цель создать тут же папку -project и в ней собрать разные отдельные программки на python

Comment: Ну смотрите, судя по всему вам точно нужно просто сделать `source`, потому что если у вас есть `venv`, то файлы, в теории, могут лежать где-угодно, нужно просто активировать виртуальное окружение. То есть, что вам надо:
1. сделать виртуальное окружение. 2. когда захотите запускать "разные отдельные программки", то просто сделайте `source path_to_venv/bin/activate`, и сделайте ./script.py. Мне кажется это должно сработать, по крайней мере я не вижу признаков обратного

Comment: Окружение я активировал sourse work3.7/bin/activate и файл ./script.py работает, но у меня будет много таких файлов и поэтому создал папку ./projects/script.py но теперь скрипт не работает, выдает ошибку импорта подключаемых библиотек.

Comment: То есть если сделать `source  work3.7/bin/activate` и потом `cd path_to_script`; `./script.py`, то оно не работает?

Comment: ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import - вот такая ошибка (я там numpy подключаю), но если запускаю файл ./script.py который находится не в папке project, то работает все

Comment: Честно говоря меня это увидило. К сожалению, сейчас не смогу проверить у себя, могу только завтра с утра помочь с этим :). Может быть кто-нибудь другой подскажет если вас нужно срочно

Comment: Спасибо за участие) это не срочно, просто недавно файл в папке работал, сегодня в ней не работает - я пересоздавал окружение, хотелось бы для себя понять причину

Comment: Так-с, я посмотрел у себя, действительно не работает, но интернет говорит, что такого поведения не должно быть... Так что нужно ждать более опытных людей в этой теме :)

Comment: Спасибо за участие:)